# difference between bootstrp.css and bootstrap-responsive.min.css file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Earlier I have used `bootstrap.min.css` for making the web page responsive. But I found `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` file along with that file.

So, can anyone tell me the requirement of this `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` as we have already `bootstrap.min.css` which behaves like a responsive design well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap version 2 used the `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` for responsive sites.

But [current Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is responsive automatically, it does not use bootstrap-responsive.min.css

So: you should be using Bootstrap version 3. It is responsive. It does not need a "responsive" CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap.min.css - it's not responsive css file , it's contain the css for UI . 
the colors , grid system , tables , buttons .. etc

bootstrap-responsive.min.css - it's responsive css file .

BTW go with new [bootstrap](https://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgetbootstrap.com%2F&ei=mjq5U9aYL8rT7Ab6_YDwBA&usg=AFQjCNGqJZetnaefv01M-l2VBolDSsiGFQ&sig2=EbKUhDJZj5MCWrqVOtyLxQ)  .